# eval javascript text from html body

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, bash, sed

I have a bash script using curl that download a page, then use grep and sed to extract javascript inside the html block to a file, so after it I use node to evaluate and use javascript downloaded.
is something like:

```
curl 'http://...' ... | grep -E "(varxpto\(|fnxpto)" | sed 's|<[/]\?script[^>]*>||g' > fn.js  
x="$(node -pe "var fs = require('fs'); eval( fs.readFileSync('fn.js')+'' ); 
var val=fnxpto('${PW}'); val;")"
```

it works like a charm using bash. but I need to expose it as a service, so I trying to do it in nodejs.

My problem is... how to do it? I tried xpath but seems it needs xmldoc as prereq and xmldoc do not parse my html (it think it's exclusive for xml, not html).

Not what I want, but I trying to exec the grep/sed too as workarround for my problem.

NOTE: I have the html text recovered using require('http') I don't need help here. Only on extract javascript from the html and import/evaluate it.

Anyone has any idea of how can I extract javascript text script from a html and evaluate it in node?

Comment: If xmldoc isn't parsing your HTML, then your HTML is invalid and therefore sucks.

Comment: +niet-the-dark-absol, yes I know, but change the html input is out of question. The javascript inside the tag <script>...</script> in html is valid. I need extract it. and eval it. only this.
Maybe there is a way to ignore invalid tags in xmldoc ?

Comment: When dirty html is your problem, perhaps tidy it up? : https://www.npmjs.org/package/htmltidy -- otherwise and besides you really shouldn't do this, why not use the same method as in bash and use a regex to extract what you want? (There are good reasons why not to do this)

Comment: Scheintod, I looking for simplicity, I think the spawn child_process pipe control a bit confuse. This is the reason I want to do it purely in nodejs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like [`cheerio`](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) to parse the HTML and then query the document for script tags:

```
// `data` is the entire string response from `http.request()`
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    $ = cheerio.load(data);

$('script').each(function(i, elem) {
  console.dir($(this).text());
  // do eval() or whatever else here
});
```